# Enviar Ctrl + ^ a una terminal en distribuciones de teclado donde ^ se escribe presionando doble vez la tecla

Tags: linux, terminal

En los teclados con distribución para el idioma español latino (y creo recordar que también para el español de España) el caret (^) sirve como símbolo individual y como acento. Cuando quieres usarlo como acento sobre una letra tienes que escribir Alt + {tecla correspondiente} seguido de la letra. En cambio, cuando quieres escribir el caret solo, tienes que usar Alt y luego presionar dos veces {tecla correspondiente}.

Esta forma de escribir el caret no parece permitir escribir Ctrl + ^ a una terminal. En este caso la terminal es Konsole en un entorno de escritorio plasma, pero he visto el mismo comportamiento en otros entornos.

Estoy usando este programa para detectar los códigos que recibe la terminal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { CTRL_C = 3 };

void modo_raw(void)
{
    system("stty raw -echo");
}

void salir_modo_raw(void)
{
    system("stty -raw echo");
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    atexit(salir_modo_raw);
    modo_raw();

    while ((c = getchar()) != CTRL_C) {
        printf("%d ", c);
    }
}
```

He intentado varias combinaciones, pero solo recibo el código de un caret normal (94), los códigos de los otros símbolos que están en la misma tecla o a veces nada en absoluto.

¿Conocen alguna forma de enviar esta combinación de teclas a la terminal?

Comment: No se si a ti te pasa, pero en terminal yo puedo escribir ese caracter pulsando a la vez "shift" y la tecla donde esta (que en mi teclado de distribución española es la misma tecla del acento grave), y luego, al soltar esa combinacion, tan solo me hace falta pulsar la barra de espacio y aparece... ¿a ti no te pasa?  ^^

Comment: @masterguru Muy similar. Si presiono AltGr + {tecla de acento grave} + espacio me sale un ^. Pero, si añado control (Control + AltGr + {tecla de acento grave} + espacio) la terminal solo recibe el código 94 (equivalente a ^), en lugar de recibir Ctrl + ^ que aparentemente en mi sistema es 30.

Comment: Ah, vale, perdona, no te habia entendido... me pregunto con que propósito debes mandar dicha combinación de teclas a un terminal... ¿que esperas que ocurra con ello?  No lo se, por eso pregunto, tengo curiosidad.

Comment: @masterguru De hecho es un comando de vim/neovim, y quería ver si lo puedo ejecutar directamente antes de pensar en crear atajos para hacer lo mismo. Pero supongo que al final si terminaré haciéndolo.